# Fastest way to transform dictionary/json keys to be MongoDB acceptable (convert "." and "$" to something else)

Tags: python, json, mongodb, python-2.7, dictionary

TLDR: What's the fastest way to replace **all** keys containing "." or "$" with an underscore?

---

No surprise to anyone using MongoDB but you can't have "." or "$" as any key in your document. It's easy enough if you are the creator of all the keys in the first place, and therefore can just choose your names wisely. In my case, I'm getting the data by pulling from an external API and so I can't do anything about their conventions...

I realize I could convert each of the individual keys one by one like this:

```
APIdict[key_num_1] = APIdict.pop(key.num.1)
APIdict[key_num_2] = APIdict.pop(key.num.2)
APIdict[key_num_3] = APIdict.pop(key.num.3)
...
```

But that presumes I know all the keys before hand and can get messy/long.

Is there any way to parse all the keys in the dictionary and rename all the ones containing an "." with a corresponding key using an underscore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not ideal, but I used dictionary comprehension to just create a new dictionary in one line...

Assume that "a" is your "bad" dictionary.

<s>a_cleaned = {key.replace(".","_"): a[key] for key in a.keys()}</s>

Thanks to Valentin Lorentz for the improvement:

```
a_cleaned = {key.replace(".","_"): value for (key, value) in a.items()}
```

Comment: Use this: `a_cleaned = {key.replace(".","_"): value for (key, value) in a.items()}`